# CORS https access to localhost works on Chrome but NOT on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ssl, google-apps-script, cors

I am running into a CORS issue on firefox and IE while Chrome seems to handle the same scenario just fine.

I have a requirement to access a local mongoose server from a web app running in the browser. I send XMLHTTP request from my web app which is a Google App Script - HTMLService (that is served from `https://script.google.com` ) to local client that is running a mongoose server running on localhost - 127.0.0.1:1234 . The XMLHTTP request is sent to

```
https://localhost:1234/ping
```

over HTTPS (GET). The server should respond with "PING_OK" message as plain text.
We also point the browser to

```
https://localhost:1234/ping
```

to have our test certificated accepted as a trusted source.
After the above steps, Chrome browser is able to access the local mongoose server, but Firefox fails with the message **"NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"** (IE also fails)

Also a test html page when served from `file:///c:test.html` is also able to access

```
https://localhost:1234/ping
```

via Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the javascript in the html :

```
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }


  //  set the onreadystatechange callback
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var xStatus = ['UNSENT','OPENED','HEADERS_RECEIVED','LOADING','DONE'];
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var response =  xmlhttp.responseText;
        console.log('Response: '+response);
    } else if((xmlhttp.readyState>0) && (xmlhttp.readyState<4)){
        console.log('state='+ xStatus[xmlhttp.readyState]+', status='+ xmlhttp.statusText);
    } else {
        console.log('state='+ xStatus[xmlhttp.readyState]+', status='+ xmlhttp.statusText);
      }
  }


  //  set the timeout value and the ontimeout callback

  xmlhttp.timeout = 30000;
  xmlhttp.ontimeout = function() {
       console.log('XHR timed out');
  }

  var url = 'https://localhost:1234/ping';
  var params = '';


  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(params);
```

The server certificate is a test certificate generated with openSSL for ""OTHER" ( Mongoose-c++) and set with the following options.

Here is the code on the mongoose server side on the local machine.

```
void FakeWebServer::handlePingRequest(struct mg_connection *conn) {

/// Set headers
mg_send_header(conn, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
mg_send_header(conn, "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
mg_send_header(conn, "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER");
mg_send_header(conn, "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");

mg_send_header(conn, "Content-Type", "text/plain");

/// Send Fake Message
std::string msg = "PING_OK";
mg_send_data(conn, msg.c_str(), strlen(msg.c_str()));
}
```

The above code when deployed as a webapp via google app scripy happily works in Chrome but Firefox fails with "NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied"

I am relatively new to javascript programming and I am not sure if this is an SSL related issue I am facing or a CORS one...

1) Am I missing any additional parameters or config in this kind of ssl access on either end?

2) Also why would a page served from  file:///*html be able to access

```
https://localhost:1234
```

via CORS while the exact same html when served from

```
https://script.google.com
```

fail on Firefox (and IE).

Any pointers and suggestions to resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be an open issue with Caja sanitization. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3543 .

We are totally stuck on this one. We are looking for any suggestions on possible hacks workarounds or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where Chrome and IE work fine, but Firefox fails when calling a WebAPI from JavaScript using Dojo. It turns out that the "accept" headers being sent by Firefox are different, and not supported by my API. 
Chrome sends this:

```
Accept: */*
```

Firefox sends this:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

So, Firefox receives a 500 error. I solved the problem by overriding the header in the JavaScript call. Here's the code using Dojo + TypeScript, but you should be able to do something similar in your environment.

```
    var d = new Deferred();
    var token = this._getToken();
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        handleAs: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    };
    request<Object>(url, options).then(
        function (result) {
            d.resolve(result);
        },
        function (err) {
            d.reject(err, true);
        }
    );
    return d.promise;
```

This is just a workaround. The real problem was that because of Firefox's "Accept" header, the WebAPI was trying to return the response in XML format. I never setup my data transfer objects to format as XML, so the WebAPI was throwing a 500 error. So, as a final solution, I removed the XMLFormatter from the WebAPI like this:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

An even more permanent solution would be to make the WebAPI handle XML, but I'm not doing that now.

Comment: @Morris thats interesting to know. We will try that if we revisit that project again and update here.